# Speeding up Table of a Table

Tags: performance-tuning

Here's my code:

```
k[nu_, l_, x_, y_] := Block[{},
   If [Norm[x - y] == 0,
    1,
    Exp[-Norm[x - y]/l]
    ]
   ];

(*I know "nu" does nothing...*)

Kint[X1_, X2_, l_] := Block[{},
  Table[Table[k[1/2, l, X1[[i]], X2[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[X2]}], {i, 1,
     Length[X1]}]
```

Kint will receive two matrices, and apply the k function to the rows of the matrices.

Is there a way to speed up the Kint function?

Comment: Why do you need `Block[{},...]` in either case - it's doing nothing? And you don't need `Table` of `Table`, just use a single table with two ranges (j first then i). In fact you don't need any tables, the `Kint` could be written more simply as `Outer[k[1/2, l, #1, #2] &, X1, X2]`

Comment: The `k` function doesn't use argument `nu`. You could also avoid recalculating the norm by doing `k[l_,x_,y_] := With[{n = Norm[x - y]}, If[n > 0, Exp[-n/l], 1]]`

Comment: @flinty thanks for the comments. I've tried your Outer function, but it does not return the same output... it gives a list with several levels, instead of a matrix.

Comment: @flinty but Outer[k[1/2, l, #1, #2] &, X1, X2, 1] did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking down the basic computation, faster and faster for machine floating-point:

```
x1 = RandomReal[2, {260, 3}];
x2 = RandomReal[2, {260, 3}];
kk = Kint[x1, x2, 4];
ll = 4;
kkk = Outer[Exp[-Norm[#1 - #2]/ll] &, x1, x2, 1]; // RepeatedTiming
kkk = Exp[-Sqrt[#]/ll] &@
    Outer[# . # &[#1 - #2] &, x1, x2, 1]; // RepeatedTiming
kkk = Exp[-Sqrt[#]/ll] &@
    Outer[Compile[{{a, _Real, 1}, {b, _Real, 1}}, # . # &[a - b]], 
      x1, x2, 1]; // RepeatedTiming
kkk = Exp[-Sqrt[#]/ll] &@Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}, {y, _Real, 2}},
      Table[# . # &[a - b], {a, x}, {b, y}]][x1, x2]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.250835, Null}
  {0.145463, Null}
  {0.0411549, Null}
  {0.0128501, Null}
*)

kk == kkk (* pick any kkk *)
(*  True  *)
```

Timings for `Length[x1] == Length[x2] == 20`:

```
(*
  {0.00146931, Null}
  {0.0012165, Null}
  {0.00173288, Null}
  {0.000937144, Null}
*)
```

The third method starts to become reliably faster than the first two around a length of `25` or more on my computer.

Comment: Many Thanks Michael  ;)